# Why can't I use a hex-color $var in transparentize (inside a @each loop)

Tags: sass

I'm trying to pass the variable $color as a background with opacity:

```
$buttons: (
    ("success", "#36B54A"),
    ("warning", "#CCC"),
);

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius:5px;
    min-width:180px;
    margin: 0;

    @each $button in $buttons {

        &.#{nth($button, 1)} {
            $color: #{nth($button, 2)};
            border: 1px solid $color;
            color: $color;
            background: transparentize($color, 0.8);

                &:hover {
                    background: $color;
                    color:  #FFF;
                }
        }
    }

    &.large {height: 50px;}
    &.fill  {width:100%;}
}
```

The question on my mind is: Why won't the variable in the transparentize work..?
If I use it like this, no problem.

```
$color: #666;

body{
    background: transparentize($color, .8);
}
```

I've even tried cutting up my button in RGB like so (probably makes no sense at all):

```
$buttons: (
    ("success", "54", "181", "74"),

// rest of code here
&.#{nth($button, 1)} {
        $colorR: #{nth($button, 2)};
        $colorG: #{nth($button, 3)};
        $colorB: #{nth($button, 4)};

background:rgba($colorR, $colorG, $colorB, .5);
```

And of course like so:

```
background:rgba($color, .5);
```

I've been trying different methods like 'from_hex and different mixins, but still getting the "$color: "#36B54A" is not a color for `transparentize'" error.

Can anybody explain to me what's going on..?

Comment: no duplicate post imo, was an other problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the documentation of [transparentize](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#transparentize-instance_method), you can see that the variables are passing without quotes.

One valid option, is to pass the exact value of the string, without *#{}*, transparentize process it correctly:

```
$buttons: ("success", #36B54A),("warning", #CCC);

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius:5px;
    min-width:180px;
    margin: 0;

    @each $button in $buttons {

        &.#{nth($button, 1)} {
            $color: nth($button, 2);
            border: 1px solid $color;
            color: $color;
            background: transparentize($color, 0.8);

                &:hover {
                    background: $color;
                    color:  #FFF;
                }
        }
    }

    &.large {height: 50px;}
    &.fill  {width:100%;}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks! And above all thanks for the explanation, should've done my homewerk better regarding the reading of the SASS documentation. Now I actually understand what the error-message was trying to tell me, and why it was there in the first place.